# import from config file when using src subfolder

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

I'd like to use my `get_data()` from `/src/cool_api.py` in:

- a) `cool_api.py`'s main block
- b) `main.py`'s main block

`get_data()` needs to import the API key from config/api_config.yaml which results in FileNotFoundError when trying b). **Is there a default (non-hacky) solution for imports like this from `src`?**

I have the following file structure:

```
|─ config
│  ├─ api_config.yaml
|─ src # marked as Sources Root folder in Pycharm 
│  ├─ cool_api.py
│  └─ ...
├─ tests
│  └─ test_cool_api.py
└─ main.py
```

my code:

```
# cool_api.py
def get_data():
    import yaml
    import requests

    with open("../config/api_config.yaml") as f:
        config = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
    return f"cool_api.org?key={config['api_key']}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_data())
```

a) works.

```
# main.py
from cool_api.py import get_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_data())
```

b) results in a `FileNotFoundError`. No such file or directory: '../config/api_config.yaml'

### How to fix my import statements?

#### optionally: Is there a shortcut for Pycharm users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with imports, since you're not importing the YAML file, you're opening it as a file, and you're using a relative path that is relative to the working directory of the Python process. You're getting a FileNotFound error because the working directory is the directory where `main.py` resides, and one directory up from there, there won't be a `config/` directory.

If you know the configuration file will always be relative to `cool_api.py` like that, use `__file__` (which is a builtin pointing to the absolute path to the module), and compute a path from there.

```
import os

config_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'config')
config_file = os.path.join(config_dir, 'config.yaml')

with open(config_file):
   ...
```

As for imports, I'd like to say your file structure is suboptimal; the only reason you can `import cool_api` in `main.py` right now is because PyCharm fixes up your Python sources path to include `src/`; if you try to `python main.py` in the console, it wouldn't work.

I would recommend structuring your code as a package in your project root:

```
cool_api/
  __init__.py  # likely mostly empty
  __main__.py  # main entry point
  config.py    # contains `get_data` and others
```

Packages with a `__main__` module can be launched with (e.g.) `python -m cool_api` or the Run Configuration -> Target type: "Module Name" (instead of "Script Path") option in PyCharm.

Running with that option has the additional benefit that Python itself fixes up your module path so `import cool_api.config` always works, and `from .config import get_data` works within the package, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Could you add an empty `__init__.py` file inside the config folder